# Изменение графика для ограниченного нормального распределения в R

Tags: r

Имеется кредитный  рейтинг по выгоде/убытку (отмечены разными цветами). Банк выдаёт кредит, если рейтинг его устраивает. При создании графика возникает проблема: нет чёткого разделения по цветам. График на основе функции рандома всегда изменяется, но в целом примерно одинаков. Как поставить кредитный порог, чтобы все хорошие (фиолетовые) заёмщики получили кредит, а плохие (оранжевые) - нет? Как записать формулу, считающую число, при котором возможно получить кредит, что зависит от порога?

```
library(msm)  
mrb = 15 # средний рейтинг плохих
mrg = 35 # средний рейтинг хороших
sdb = 10; sdg=10 # стандартное отклонение
Nb = 100; Ng = 100 # численность групп
a1=round(rtnorm(Nb,mrb,sdb,0,100))
a2=round(rtnorm(Ng,mrg,sdg,0,100))
library(plotly)
d=rbind(data.frame(rating=a1, group=1), data.frame(rating=a2, group=2))
d=d[order(d$rating),]
d$y=ave(d$rating, d$rating, FUN=seq_along)
d$group=as.factor(d$group)
#  график
a <- list(
  autotick = FALSE,
  ticks = "",
  tick0 = 0,
  dtick = 1,
  ticklen = 10,
  tickwidth = 2,
  tickcolor = toRGB("blue")
)
col =c('coral', 'blueviolet')
# график
plot_ly()  %>%
  add_trace(data = d, x= ~ rating, y= ~y, type = 'scatter', mode = 
'markers',
        color=~group, colors=col, marker=list(size=10)) %>%
  layout(margin = list(l = 150, r = 20, b = 40, t = 10),
     yaxis = c(a, zeroline = FALSE, showgrid = FALSE, title =
                 paste0('количество претендентов', 
 "\n&nbsp;","\n&nbsp;")),
     xaxis = list(zeroline = FALSE, showgrid = FALSE, title = "Кредитный 
 рейтинг")
 )
```

[image: График ограниченного нормального распределения]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb5bR.png

Comment: Приведите ваш код

Comment: @dIm0n
добавлено в вопрос

Comment: @dIm0n нет ли у вас идей, какую хотя бы примерно функцию нужно взять?

Comment: Нет, с R знаком поверхностно. Тут это не самый популярный язык